# Pickle as a performance benchmark, or, speedier containment checks

Tags: python

I'm loading a data structure from a CSV. The resultant structure is several collection classes composed of item objects, each of which have one or two attributes that point children or parents in the other collections.

It's not very much data. The CSV is 800KB. Loading the data structure from CSV currently takes me about **3.5 seconds**. Initially, I had some `O(n^2)` code  that was getting clobbered by containment lookups that took execution to the full `n^2`, but I've added a bit of indexing and really reduced that.

Now my weak points are still containment lookups, but linear. It's frustrating when the most time-consuming components of your program are repeated executions of code like:

```
def add_thing(thing):
    if thing not in things:
        things.append(thing)
```

I may be missing something (I hope I am!) but it appears there's nothing much I can do to speed these up. I don't want the `things` collection to contain the same `thing` more than once. To do that, I must check every single item that's already there. Perhaps there is a faster `list` that can do this for me? A C-based, dupe-free `list`?

Anyway, I thought I would pickle the resultant data structure and see how long it took to `load`. Admittidely, I have no idea what goes into unpickling, but my thinking is that unpickling must be closer to raw I/O since the data structure itself is already laid out in the pickle. I was surprised to learn `pickle.load`ing this data structure takes **2.4 seconds**. Only 30% faster than my CSV slop. cPickle does the same job in **0.4 seconds**, but I'm trying to keep this as apples-to-apples as possible, which I realize I may have already failed at. But I hope you can see my train of thought and criticize its weak points.

So, what am I to gather, if anything, from the exercise?

- The performance of `pickle.load` and my CSV loading code have nothing to do with each other, and I should not be comparing them?
- Things like this just take a long time?
- I can optimize my containment lookups further?
- I've got it all wrong?

(N.B. I'm using cProfile for profiling)

Comment: Although this is a bit of abstract, I'll throw an idea out there - how about keeping "things" as the `list` named `things` and the `set` called `sthings`?

Comment: Does the order of `things` matter? If not, why not use a set?

Comment: That's a good point. I will try a set. Just went with a list for no good reason. No, the other doesn't matter. Set containment is faster?

Comment: You should also consider using cPickle! :)
"cPickle is written in C, so it can be up to 1000 times faster than pickle."
- I see that you already tried this. My mistake

Comment: Set containment is ~O(1); list containment is O(n).  See the [time complexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) page.  But it'd probably be simpler just to make a set directly from the iteration, come to think of it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the `set` tip and the time complexity page! I will give this a shot. I knew something had to be off

Comment: Funny thing about `set`s—they are dubbed "Unordered collections of unique elements" :) :)

Comment: Yes, 3.5 seconds to 0.5 seconds just by using `set`s. Lessons learned. Thank you. So now, it's interesting, because `pickle.load` takes much longer than my `set`-based code. I guess `pickle` is `pickle`, and `cPickle` is very fast.